# Connect to Firestore using Python as client with limited permissions

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, python-requests, firebase-security

I searched a lot about this and couldn't find what I'm looking for. What I want to do is simply **connect to Firestore as a client app** respecting Firestore Rules, the same way I do that with Android or Javascript Web.

I found [this google maintained library](https://googleapis.dev/python/firestore/latest/index.html) that show a client **Firestore API**, but I couldn't find a way to use Firebase Application Credentials to initialize it.

What I want to do is exactly what [Pyrebase](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase) shows that is possible to do with **Realtime Database**. Buy sadly, Pyrebase do not support Firestore.

```
import pyrebase

# What I wish to do, but can't use Firestore with Pyrebase
config = {
  "apiKey": "apiKey",
  "authDomain": "projectId.firebaseapp.com",
  "databaseURL": "https://databaseName.firebaseio.com",
  "storageBucket": "projectId.appspot.com"
}

firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
```

At a web app, since the app is initialized the way shown, user is able to login with email and password.

So my question is: **How to connect to Firestore as a client?** Is there any **other library** or method to do the same that Pyrebase does to Realtime Database?

I really don't think that's possible so I found this Firebase [Auth Rest API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/) but I really don't know how to use it in order to achieve the point when the user insert his email and password.

Could you please give me a **step-by-step** usage of  this API or a library to connect a Python Client as an front-end application?

Comment: You're correct: there's not an easy way to do this in Python. In Node.js, you could potentially use the Web SDK for a client side app. In Python, as you describe, you would first need to [use the REST API to sign in a user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/#section-sign-in-email-password).  Once you sign someone in and get an identity token, you can [use it with the Firestore REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api) to send requests that go through your Security Rules.

Comment: If you have a minute, please also [file a feature request](https://github.com/googleapis/python-firestore/issues/new/choose) for the Firestore python library.